# Unable to find org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am having a java-maven project. It copies files from local to HDFS. I am having hadoop-common in my pom.xml. Still, it is failing with the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration
    at apache.spark.poc.utils.FileProcessor.<clinit>(FileProcessor.java:60)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 1 more
```

Below are dependencies from my pom.xml:
Is there anything that I am missing out here? I also checked it via the IDE, and I am able to see hadoop-common and Configuration class under the jar.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
  <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.1</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming_2.10 -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.1</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming-kafka_2.10 -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka_2.10</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.3</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql_2.10 -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.1</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11 -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.1</version>
  <!-- <scope>provided</scope> -->
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
  <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
  <version>0.10.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
  <artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>0.11.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
  <version>2.6.3</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>mysql</groupId>
  <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
  <version>5.1.44</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-dbcp2 -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
  <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
  <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
  <version>3.1</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-common -->
```

Comment: Try to include `hadoop-client` in your dependencies as well.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But it did not help. Strange thing is, I am able to see the Configuration class under the External_Dependencies -> hadoop-common-2.2.0.jar -> org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration. Still, while executing, I am not able to find it.

Comment: Your versions are all over the place... First of all, Spark Kafka already includes Kafka clients. Secondly, if you include Spark YARN, you can remove the (old) Hadoop version. Finally, do not combine Spark 1.6 and 2 dependencies

Comment: Also, you don't need Spark just to copy local files to HDFS... Your Hadoop POM version should match your running Hadoop cluster as well

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comment, will implement and revert back my findings.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. It was scoped as provided. I did a one-by-one analysis of the libraries and checked what all is getting deployed.

hadoop-common library was being picked along with spark-core. But, spark-core was marked as **provided** scope. Hence, it was available during compilation phase, but was not available when I ran it via IntelliJ.

Issue fixed.